# Javascript: submit form specyfing content type

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, http, content-type

I use this code to submit a form

```
var form = $("#some-form");
form.attr("action", url);
form.attr("method", "post");
form.attr('target', '_blank');
form.submit();
```

The problem is that the request sent has `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963480/firefox-and-chrome-replacing-lf-with-crlf-during-post)) encodes `\n` characters in textareas of the form as `%0D%0A`, which are decoded as `\r\n` on the server side and cause many troubles.

I want the server to receive `\n`, so I need another content type.

So, the questions are:

- what content type should I use?
- how should I change my javascirpt to use that content type?

**EDIT**

I tried `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, but it encodes new line characters the same way.

Comment: The only other content type is multipart/form-data but that's for posting files.

Comment: Why do you need newline to be encoded as \n on the server?

Comment: Some other components of the system do not accept `\r\n`. Even if that was not the case, the current behaviour kind of sucks, because the transport component (HTTP) limits end users expressiveness: the user cannot insert "foo\rbar\r\n" into the form so that the server receives that exact value.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `xmlHTTPrequest` (AJAX)

it is asynchronous and submits the data to the page. Plus you can specify the header. \n should arrive as \n on the server with AJAX.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
request.method = "post";
request.open(request.method, [url] , true); //true is asynchronous

//this part here matters. regular form data with charset UTF-8
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=UTF-8");
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

request.onreadystatechange = [trackingfunction]; //You can see which data is returned from the post.

request.send([arg]); //send the post arguments here!
```

This seems to work on my machine. Save the data into a file and Notepad doesn't register the `\n` as a newline. It should've when the `LF` was converted to `CR LF`

[image: LF in saved file in Notepad++]

Comment: In my case AJAX is not an option, I want to submit a form in a new tab.

Comment: @Bartosz Marcinkowski Can you clarify the submitting in new tab for me?

Comment: AJAX means that my request is constructed in Javascript and the response is handled by Javascript. Submiting a form means that (in my case) the Javascript tells the browser to submit the form (act as if the user clickied on a submit button of a form), and then the response contains HTML, not JSON data, and (in my case) the browser opens received HTML in a new tab.

Comment: Actually Ajax originally was designed to receive xml. JSON is also possible. You can however construct a page on the server, send the HTML back and load this into a new tab using AJAX? Does effectively the same thing with the added bonus that you control the html-output client side.

Comment: I would have to manually fill JSON with form data and modify my server side views to accept JSON instead of POST data. That is not the same.

Comment: An AJAX request sends post data just the same way to the server as a form submit. Do you like me to provide you a sample?

Comment: No, thank you. If AJAX is the only way I know how to do this. The reason I asked the question is that I though doing it with a form will be simple as `form.attr("foo", "bar")`. +1 for effort :)